# Error in updating the score in a game

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

I have problem when i updating score in the game i make i dont know what is the problem but when i shoot something the score should increment by 1 but in my code sometimes it increment by 2 or 3 sometimes 1 it not constant i dont know why this happen here is the code i used

```
@interface GameScene () {

    SKLabelNode* _scoreLabelNode;
    NSInteger _score;


}


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    _score = 0;
        _scoreLabelNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Silom Regular"];
        _scoreLabelNode.fontSize = 50;
        _scoreLabelNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width - 335 , self.size.height - 60);
        _scoreLabelNode.zPosition = 100;
        [self addChild:_scoreLabelNode];

        _scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_score];
}

if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ObjectCategory) {

        _score++;
        _scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_score];
}
```

Comment: add breakpoint on _score++ , just to check how many times it's getting incremented

Comment: Where did you write this if condition `if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ObjectCategory)` ? on which event ?

Comment: See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28527280/3402095 If nothing from that post can't be applied to your code, you can try with something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23367987/3402095

Comment: @NeverHopeless in this -(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {

Comment: @Misha i put "NSLog (@"%d", _score )" after "_score++" it increment as should like 10 11 12 .. etc  but the score jumped from 10 to 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few similar issue with this delegate, see if this may fix your issue:

[SpriteKit: didBeginContact being called non-stop on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406645/spritekit-didbegincontact-being-called-non-stop-on-ipad)

[Why are didBeginContact called multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228274/why-are-didbegincontact-called-multiple-times)

[didBeginContact is being called multiple times for the same SKPhysicsBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956637/didbegincontact-is-being-called-multiple-times-for-the-same-skphysicsbody)

Even if it doesn't solve your problem, you can use a flag variable to handle this score update for once. e.g.,

```
bool hasScoreUpdated;

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact * _Nonnull)contact
{
    if(!hasScoreUpdated)
    {
        _score++;
        hasScoreUpdated = true;
    }
     // your rest of the logic
}

- (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact * _Nonnull)contact
{
    hasScoreUpdated = false;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment above:

> i put "NSLog (@"%d", _score )" after "_score++" it increment as should
>   like 10 11 12 .. etc but the score jumped from 10 to 12

It is possibly due to the very frequently calling the respective event and a very rapidly update of UI element.

Comment: thank u but the link "Why are didBeginContact called multiple times?"above broken

Comment: can i ask you something outside this question , i want to set the touch only in specific area in the scene do you know how i can do that ?

Comment: Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656896/set-touchable-area-of-skspritenode